# Is there any known recurence formula for this sequence $A214645$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, formal-power-series

$A214645$ is the sequence of Exponential Generating function with radius of convergence $r=0$ , really I'm interesting to know if this sequence which [mentioned in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A214645) satisfies any known recurrence formula ?

**Note:** The exponential Generating function with radius of convergence $r=0$ has a wide  application in number theory and graph